# Using solc to compile contract that imports local OpenZeppelin contracts

Tags: contract-deployment, nodejs, openzeppelin, solcjs

I am trying to compile and deploy a contract based on OpenZeppelin using Node.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const input = fs.readFileSync("./BaseContract.sol", "utf8");
  const compiledInput = solc.compile(input);
  ... 
});
```

However, when this function is called I get the following error

```
ParserError: Source \"node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol\" not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport \"./node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol\";
```

Here is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Base is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("Base", "BAS") {
    }

    function mint(
      address _to,
      uint256 _tokenId
    )
      external
    {
      _safeMint(_to, _tokenId);
    }
}
```

I have installed @openzeppelin into node_modules using `yarn add @openzeppelin/contracts`, and the relevant files are in node_modules folder. I understand that solc cannot fetch over network, but the files are installed locally so that shouldn't be the problem.

What can I do to troubleshoot here?

Comment: What solc version are you using? Newer version have a different input parameter. In that version you can supply a callback that will be invoked to resolve imports, see the details in the readme file https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#example-usage-with-import-callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this error because I did not specify all the relevant sources for solc (version ^0.8.0). I solved the issue by writing a recursive function that compiles all the dependencies in the correct format.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

// returns a contract object compiled using solc
// baseContractPath: relative path of the base contract, i.e. "./BaseContract.sol"
const instantiateContract = (baseContractPath) => {
  const sources = {};
  compileImports(baseContractPath, sources);

  var input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: sources,
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": ["*"],
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const output = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input));
  const contract = JSON.parse(output);
  const bytecode =
    "0x" + contract.contracts[baseContractPath]["Base"].evm.bytecode.object;
  const abi = contract.contracts[baseContractPath]["Base"].abi;
  return {
    bytecode: bytecode,
    abi: abi,
  };
};

// returns sources: { "Contract.sol": { content: fs.readFileSync("pathName.sol",utf8)...}}
// using recursion
const compileImports = (root, sources) => {
  sources[root] = { content: fs.readFileSync(root, "utf8") };
  const imports = getNeededImports(root);
  for (let i = 0; i < imports.length; i++) {
    compileImports(imports[i], sources);
  }
};

// returns all the import paths in absolute path
const getNeededImports = (path) => {
  const file = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
  const files = new Array();
  file
    .toString()
    .split("\n")
    .forEach(function (line, index, arr) {
      if (
        (index === arr.length - 1 && line === "") ||
        !line.trim().startsWith("import")
      ) {
        return;
      }
      // the import is legit
      const relativePath = line.substring(8, line.length - 2);
      const fullPath = buildFullPath(path, relativePath);
      files.push(fullPath);
    });
  return files;
};

// parent: node_modules/.../ERC721/ERC721.sol
// returns absolute path of a relative one using the parent path
const buildFullPath = (parent, path) => {
  let curDir = parent.substr(0, parent.lastIndexOf("/")); //i.e. ./node/.../ERC721
  if (path.startsWith("./")) {
    return curDir + "/" + path.substr(2);
  }

  while (path.startsWith("../")) {
    curDir = curDir.substr(0, curDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
    path = path.substr(3);
  }

  return curDir + "/" + path;
};

module.exports = {
  instantiateContract,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As a security measure in solc, you can't compile contracts that come from a parent or adjacent folders of the directory you are in. you can add the paths you want to allow for compilation by adding them one by one using `--allow-path` like follows :

```
 --allow-path "/path/to/folderOne" --allow-path "/path/to/folderTwo"
```

A better option is to use `truffle compile`, build a new truffle project or add your contracts to an existing project and use the `truffle compile` command and it will do the path adding automatically and without any hassle.